# Corrupted Symfony 2 vendors install

Tags: php, git, symfony

Facts: using standard Symfony 2.0.10 release (includes vendors) **all works fine**. However with "without-vendors" release something get corrupted after issuing:

```
php bin/vendors install
```

Files are fetched but, at the end, accessing any page under `web/` ends with **Aborted connection**. I'm manually installing vendors becuase of doctrine fixtures.

I don't know if the cause is [Git for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) and i'm going to investingate this. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: same happens with new version of Symfony (2.0.11). No errors after installing vendors but got **Aborted connection** requesting any Symfony2 page.

**EDIT**: this is the error.log file found in Apache2 logs directory after cleaning up and requesting `http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/_configurator/`:

```
[Sun Feb 26 03:04:22 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Feb 26 03:04:22 2012] [notice] Server built: Feb 22 2012 19:25:43
[Sun Feb 26 03:04:22 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2588
[Sun Feb 26 03:04:22 2012] [notice] Child 2588: Child process is running
[Sun Feb 26 03:04:22 2012] [notice] Child 2588: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sun Feb 26 03:04:22 2012] [notice] Child 2588: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun Feb 26 03:04:22 2012] [notice] Child 2588: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sun Feb 26 03:04:22 2012] [notice] Child 2588: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sun Feb 26 03:04:33 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
```

Comment: Do you see anything strange in the output of this command? Or in your web server log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to myself: the problem seems to be the checkout style: i'm under Windows and i've used "Checkout Windows style, commit Unix style". This causes (for some reason i can't understand) Apache crash with 255 status.

Setting Git for using "Checkout Unix style, commit Unix style" **fixed the problem**. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I've been having this problem and this fixed it - thanks. For reference anyone else having the issue should set GIT config so in the [core] it has `autocrlf = false`.

Answer (score 1):

open your deps file; and change the address of the git repositories: http for https; this solve your problem.

After

Answer (score 1):

An outdated Git version can't handle `http://` and `http://` git repository URIs properly, at least in my experience with Debian stable.

If you see 403 errors consider updating Git to 1.7.x or replacing any occurences of `http://` and `https://` with `git://` in your `deps` file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your web server `error.log`. If connection aborts, its probably a runtime issue and is not directly related to having vendors installed manually. It could be an an issue with your cache directory.

Comment: can you double check your apache log file? should be in /var/log/httpd/error.log or /var/log/apache/error.log.

Comment: Found the problem, i've marked it as an answer... thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add doctrine-fixtures manually.

See the new target for the DoctrineFixtureBundle below:

```
[doctrine-fixtures]
git=https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures.git

[DoctrineFixturesBundle]
git=https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle
target=/bundles/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle
```

old target=/bundles/symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle

new target=/bundles/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle

To load the fixtures correctly, you have to add the type of the manager in the load function:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
//...
}
```